# How to get visible cells in GMGridView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Can i call method when visible last cell in GMGridView? 
Similar willDisplayCell method in UITableViewDelegate. Help me please :D

https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

Comment: Please be specific about your question.

Comment: This question needs more detail and context.

Comment: I need download json from server when display last cell. i'm using GMGridView. https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the [.h file for GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/blob/master/GMGridView/GMGridView.h), I don't see any method that is similar to UITableView's ["`visibleCells`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/visibleCells) or "indexPathsOfVisibleCells" methods.

[I see somebody else has opened a Git Issue](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/issues/43) with the developers of GMGridView requesting the same feature you are looking for, so you could add your comment or "+1, I need this" vote to it.  There is a *potential* bit of code you might be able to make use of at the bottom of that Git Issue.